# Как сделать localstoreage?

Tags: javascript

```
<input id="status_text" value="Last Status" onkeyup="if(event.keyCode == 13)this.blur()"/>
```

Как сделать сохранение полей?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так:

HTML:

```
<input id="status_text" value="" onkeyup="save(event)" />
```

JS:

```
const status_text = document.getElementById('status_text');
status_text.value = localStorage.getItem(status_text.id);

const save = (e) => {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const input = e.target;

    localStorage.setItem(input.id, input.value);

    console.log('Сохранено');

    input.blur();
  }
}
```

Comment: а можно сделать так, чтобы необязательно приходилось нажимать enter?

Comment: Ну да, можно убрать условие "(e.keyCode === 13)" и тогда сохраняться будет на каждый "onkeyup". Только тогда надо будет убрать ещё "e.preventDefault();" и "input.blur();", чтобы они не мешали.